# Error "io.questdb.cairo.CairoException: [2] could not open read-write [file=<dir>/_tab_index.d]"

Tags: java, spring-boot, questdb, apache-camel-3

Currently, I am testing QuestDB in a Apache Camel / Spring Boot scenario for our project. I set up a custom Camel component and a configuration bean holding the connection properties. As far as I can see, my custom Camel component properly connects to the server where a test instance of QuestDB is running. But when sending data over the Camel route, I get error messages:

```
io.questdb.cairo.CairoException: [2] could not open read-write [file=<dir>/_tab_index.d]
```

The exception is thrown when creating the CairoEngine like (taken from [QuestDB API documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/java-embedded/):

```
try (CairoEngine engine = new CairoEngine(this.configuration)) {
        ... other code ...
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ...
}
```

where `this.configuration` is of type `CairoConfiguration` and contains the "data_dir" and is instantiated like this:

```
configuration = new DefaultCairoConfiguration(<quest db directory (String)>);
```

Currently, I am passing the fully qualified path my database directory: `/srv/questdb/db`. I confirmed that the file `_tab_index.d` is available at this location.

What am I going wrong? Maybe I should mention, that I set the access rights to the questdb directory to `777`, the owner was set to `chown root:questdb ...`

Comment: I just studied the documentation once more. Could it be that the embedded Java library (providing the CairoEngine and stuff) is not meant for a client/server scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the embedded API is not suitable for what I want to do. I need to one of the other APIs. I tested my scenario withe the InfluxDB line protocol (see [Line protocol documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/develop/insert-data#influxdb-line-protocol)) and the data gets written to the server without problems.

The `doInsert` method in my custom component look like this (just for testing) which is called when building a route with the custom QuestDB "to" end point:

```
public class QuestDbProducer extends DefaultProducer {

    ... other code ...

    private void doInsert(Exchange exchange, String tableName) throws InvalidPayloadException {

         try (Sender sender = Sender.builder().address("lxyrpc01.gsi.de:9009").build()) {
            sender.table("inventors")
                .symbol("born", "Austrian Empire")
                .longColumn("id", 0)
                .stringColumn("name", "Nicola Tesla")
                .atNow();
            sender.table("inventors")
                .symbol("born", "USA")
                .longColumn("id", 1)
                .stringColumn("name", "Thomas Alva Edison")
                .atNow();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You are correct. Embedded is meant to work directly over the local filesystem, while for client-server you would need to use one of the three available interfaces: ILP (the one you are using and the most performant), REST API, or Postgres-wire protocol